# Why is my EF Core saving a new entry on my db as Excluded = 1 if I have "false" for new entries?

Tags: c#

I am a senior dev in PHP, but due to having lost my main senior dev for a C# project, I recently started messing with this and we have a part here where we upload a CSV file and it creates in our db a new entry for each corresponding price in that table.

Problem is, whenever we add a new table, the previously inserted one should in fact have a field in db which is named "Excluded" to 1, but even the newly created one is being inserted with 1 instead of 0 and so I cannot use those values in my code, I always have to go and manually change 1 to 0, which makes no sense obviously.

This is the code:

```cs
public class ProductsListingController : ListingController<IProductListingService>
{
    protected readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;
    protected readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    protected readonly ABCDbContext _context;

    public ProductsListingController(IProductListingService productListingService, IUserRepository userRepository, IFileService fileService, IProductRepository productRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ABCDbContext context)
        : base(productListingService, userRepository, fileService)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost("file")]
    public override IActionResult Add([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromQuery] FileVisibility visibility = FileVisibility.Private, [FromQuery] Guid? id = null)
    {
        bool firstLine = true;
        var PriceTable = new List<PriceTable>();

        var product = _productRepository.FindById(id.Value);

        if (product == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        product.HasPriceTable = false;

        product.PriceTable ??= new List<PriceTable>();

        string[] width = { };

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (line != null)
                {
                    var columns = line.Split(';');

                    if (firstLine)
                    {
                        width = columns;
                        firstLine = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (var x = 1; x < columns.Length; x++)
                        {
                            PriceTable.Add(new PriceTable
                            {
                                ProductId = product.Id,
                                Price = float.Parse(columns[x]),
                                Width = width[x],
                                Height = columns[0],
                                Excluded = false,
                                ExclusionUserId = null
                            });
                        }

                        product.PriceTable = PriceTable;
                        product.HasPriceTable = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        _productRepository.Update(product);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

Here's some aditional information for the "Excluded" part that I found on the code:

```
using System;

namespace ABC.Domain.Helpers.Domain
{
    public class BaseAssociationEntity<TEntity> : IAssociationEntity<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseAssociationEntity<TEntity>, IAssociationEntity<TEntity>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExclusionDate { get; set; }
        public bool Excluded { get; set; } = false;

        public virtual TEntity Seed(string key)
        {
            Id = Faithlife.Utility.GuidUtility.Create(Guid.Parse("20173be1-0e8b-460d-9867-d2a60a114b03"), key);

            return (TEntity)this;
        }

        public virtual TEntity Exclude()
        {
            Excluded = true;

            return (TEntity)this;
        }
    }
}
```

And here another part where "Excluded" is:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ABC.Domain.Helpers.Domain
{
    public class BaseEntity<TEntity> : IBaseEntity<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity<TEntity>, IBaseEntity<TEntity>
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(GuidConverter))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public bool Excluded { get; set; } = false;

        public virtual TEntity Exclude()
        {
            Excluded = true;

            return (TEntity)this;
        }

        public virtual TEntity Seed(string key)
        {
            Id = Faithlife.Utility.GuidUtility.Create(Guid.Parse("20173be1-0e8b-460d-9867-d2a60a114b03"), key);

            return (TEntity)this;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is BaseEntity<TEntity>)
            {
                return Id == ((BaseEntity<TEntity>)obj).Id;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.Equals(obj);
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this could shed some light on whoever can interpret this. :D

EDIT2:

I usually like to update the communities where I ask for help with solutions when I find it, because it might just help another person in the future, but unfortunately this time I have no clue why, but this apparently is fixed.

I've been doing a lot of changes in the code, testing etc. somehow I was testing this again to show a senior dev, my friend, to be able to help fixing it and it just worked.

Tested again and again with different files and it just worked.

So, I'm sorry, but I really cannot understand how, but it seems to be fixed!

Comment: Remove `_productRepository.Update(product);` it is not needed. Check `SaveChanges/Async` maybe you have some special entities preprocessing.

Comment: The problem is not from this piece of code...  Excluded is set to false so it should be 0. Maybe u have a DB trigger or something else that is changing it to 1.

Comment: Why this core has `product.PriceTable ??= new List<PriceTable>();`? Does your repository has overload with Include for `_productRepository.FindById(id.Value)`?

Comment: can you try changing bool to bool? . Maybe this is the issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20110

Comment: Thank you guys for your (very) quick answers. I am now trying to add-migration but this is giving me an error so I can't even test this because I am trying to add a new field in my db and I am not being able to if I can't do the migration. :( It tells me Your target project 'ABC.Client.Api' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'ABC.Infrastructure.Repository.Migrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly. :(

Comment: Well, it seems it was some kind of currupted files or whatever, so what I did was delete all BIN folders and it worked. Now, back to the problem again. @SvyatoslavDanyliv I removed that like you mentioned but did nothing. I also don't know what you mean with the overload.

Comment: @DA Yes, maybe that is the case and I might have in other place something that is doing this (it must be that), but I just don't know where and how to find it. :(

Comment: This question is marked as EF Core but there is no EF Core code in the snippet. There could potentially be unlimited places in your code where this entity is modified before it reaches the database, and optionally even triggers in the database. **Find references** on `Excluded` is probably your friend.

Comment: @joakimriedel thank you for your input. Yes, there are indeed some places where I see "Excluded = true" I just don't know how to interpret that. I guess I will have to leave this to someone else that knows it better to look at my code.